# Java Store an input value

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I need help on this.. I need to store the criteria values for later use..
For example.. I typed

- Criteria(1): Quiz
- Percentage: 25

and

- Criteria (2): Attendance
- Percentage: 75

then the program will ask

- Student Name: JavaStack
- Grade for Criteria1(which is the Quiz): 92.52
- Grade for Criteria2(which is the Attendance): 86.35

I know how to do the rest, but I do not know how to make the Criteria values will be stored to be used for the rest of the grading performance.

```
    System.out.println("How many criteria?");
    System.out.print("Answer: ");
    crit1=Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

    String critr;
    int perc;

    for(int crit=1; crit<=crit1; crit++){

        if(crit1==1){
            System.out.println("Criteria(1): ");
            critr=inpt.readLine();
            System.out.println("Percentage: 100%");
            perc=100;
        }

        System.out.print("Criteria("+ crit +"): ");
        critr=inpt.readLine();

        System.out.println("Input between 1-100 only");
        System.out.print("Percentage: ");
        perc=Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());
    }


    int grade;
    for(int name1=1; name1<=stud; name1++){
        System.out.println("Student's Name: ");
        name=inpt.readLine();

        System.out.println("Grade for " +critr+": ");
        grade=Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());
    }
```

Yes, this is a school work and I really need help on this. I hope that you can help me.
Thanks in advance! Good day.

Comment: I'm confused. You're already storing the `Criteria values` in `critr`. You're overwriting it, but you're still storing it.

Comment: You could write them to an array.

Comment: @ Justin - Yes, I know that I'm overwriting it, but I need to store the values that are inputted from it before overwriting it.

@David - I was actually thinking of doing it in array, but can I ask if it's possible for the user to input the array value? Thanks.

I'm honestly new with Java, so please take it easy on me.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of a custom class to store the data

```
class Criteria {

    public Criteria (String name, float weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String name;
    public float weight
}

System.out.println("How many criteria?");
System.out.print("Answer: ");
int critCount =Integer.parseInt(inpt.readLine());

Criteria[] sections = new Criteria[critCount];

for(int crit=0; crit < critCount; crit++){

    System.out.println("Criteria(1): ");
    String name = inpt.readLine();
    System.out.println("Percentage: 100%");
    float value = Float.parseFloat(inpt.readLine());

    sections[i] = new Criteria(name, value);
}

// ...
```